# How do I view gstreamer debug output?

Tags: gstreamer

How to view the output of functions like GST_CAT_INFO, GST_DEBUG etc?
Do I need to compile gstreamer myself with debug level set or it can be done at application level?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Debugging messages can be printed in stderr by using the GST_DEBUG environment variable (if gstreamer has been compiled with --enable-gst-debug, which is default).

For example: `GST_DEBUG=audiotestsrc:5 gst-launch audiotestsrc ! fakesink` will log everything (5) from the audiotestsrc element.

You can change your program debugging output at runtime using `setenv("GST_DEBUG","cat:level...", 1)`

Sometime reading GStreamer debugging can be tedious. You can give [gst-debug-viewer](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~cymacs/gst-debug-viewer/) a try.

You can read the [Documentation](http://www.gstreamer.net/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) for other details.

Comment: cool! many thanks for the info. 
And this is how I redirected the output to a file.
$ GST_DEBUG=audiotestsrc:5 gst-launch audiotestsrc ! fakesink 2> file.txt
It should help me in debugging gstreamer. And the good thing is it is working in windows also.
However, I am not getting any output from gst-debug-viewer. it shows the following info. in the shell but does not show any output in its window, just empty columns.
http://tinypic.com/r/io16xi/3

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to mention that gst-debug-viewer take output without colors.

Try generating the log with GST_DEBUG_NO_COLOR=1

Comment: Didn't work for me at first but I had the call to GST_DEBUG() in the plugin_init() and not the element code, moving the statement to the element code corrected the problem. Note that: Debug Level 0 only outputs printfs, Debug Level 1 includes Level 0 output and also outputs GST_ERROR(), Level 2 includes Level 1 and also outputs GST_WARNING(), Level 3 includes Level 2 and also outputs GST_INFO(), Level 4 includes Level 3 and also outputs GST_DEBUG(), and Level 5 outputs everything.

Comment: Could someone please add an example with
    setenv("GST_DEBUG","cat:level...", 1)
? I am trying to figure out why this function is crashing:
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

To show debug information for all categories, use something like

`export GST_DEBUG="*:6"`

before running your command.

Comment: To all levels you can directly go for GST_DEBUG="6"

Comment: You can also get messages from python only plugins like that `export GST_DEBUG="python:6"`. Can be used to debug plugin written in Python

Answer (score 8):

The current documentation is [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html). Some interesting excerpts, in my opinion:

> The `'*'` wildcard is also available. For example `GST_DEBUG=2,audio*:5` will use Debug Level 5 for all categories starting with the word `audio`, and 2 for all the others.

> Use `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-help` to obtain the list of all registered categories.

> GStreamer has the capability to output graph files. [Example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/images/playbin.png).

And the debug levels are:

> ```
> | # | Name    | Description                                                    |
> |---|---------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
> | 0 | none    | No debug information is output.                                |
> | 1 | ERROR   | Logs all fatal errors. These are errors that do not allow the  |
> |   |         | core or elements to perform the requested action. The          |
> |   |         | application can still recover if programmed to handle the      |
> |   |         | conditions that triggered the error.                           |
> | 2 | WARNING | Logs all warnings. Typically these are non-fatal, but          |
> |   |         | user-visible problems are expected to happen.                  |
> | 3 | FIXME   | Logs all "fixme" messages. Those typically that a codepath that|
> |   |         | is known to be incomplete has been triggered. It may work in   |
> |   |         | most cases, but may cause problems in specific instances.      |
> | 4 | INFO    | Logs all informational messages. These are typically used for  |
> |   |         | events in the system that only happen once, or are important   |
> |   |         | and rare enough to be logged at this level.                    |
> | 5 | DEBUG   | Logs all debug messages. These are general debug messages for  |
> |   |         | events that happen only a limited number of times during an    |
> |   |         | object's lifetime; these include setup, teardown, change of    |
> |   |         | parameters, etc.                                               |
> | 6 | LOG     | Logs all log messages. These are messages for events that      |
> |   |         | happen repeatedly during an object's lifetime; these include   |
> |   |         | streaming and steady-state conditions. This is used for log    |
> |   |         | messages that happen on every buffer in an element for example.|
> | 7 | TRACE   | Logs all trace messages. Those are message that happen very    |
> |   |         | very often. This is for example is each time the reference     |
> |   |         | count of a GstMiniObject, such as a GstBuffer or GstEvent, is  |
> |   |         | modified.                                                      |
> | 8 | MEMDUMP | Logs all memory dump messages. This is the heaviest logging and|
> |   |         | may include dumping the content of blocks of memory.           |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I added debug level:

```
gst-debug-level=4 {0->7}
```

It work without build gstreamer again

Answer (score 1):

Besides all these correct answers I'd like to point to this graphical tool to ease Gstreamer debug analysis:

https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_Use_Gstreamer_Debug_Viewer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after compiling the program, executed:

```
GST_DEBUG=5 ./tutorial2
```

Where tutorial2 is the name of executable.